# Enums values are the same in c++

Tags: c++, enums

I have this enum declaration in my class:

```
const enum METHODS{

    Write,
    Save,
    Update,
    Delete

};
```

But when I retrieve the value of my enums; I got this value `-842150451` for all the methods.

It should be 0,1,2,3 right?

Please help me solve this.

I put my enum values into  `map<LPCTSTR, long> m_methodMap`

`m_methodMap[_T("Save")] = Save;`
`same with other methods`

I retrieve it this way:

`cout << "Values " << m_methodMap.find(sMethodName)->second; // where sMethodName is the methods`

Comment: Can you show the code "retrieving the values?" The number you're showing is (most likely) an uninitialised `int`.

Comment: I'll suggest you always init the first enum to zero, so `write = 0`. You don't need it for the others.

Comment: this how i retrieve it..

Comment: @Angew why does he use `const` in front of `enum` **?**

Comment: @jules If no initialiser is specified for any of the enumerators, the first one is initialised to `0` automatically.

Comment: Thanks angew and jules, I put = 0 for write, its working now... but my problem comes back when I profile it with code coverage, it will return again -842150451 :(

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It's just superfluous there. It's actually a variable declaration which happens not to declare any variables :-) It just defines the enumeration type.

Comment: @user1670340 Can you *please* post the code you use to retrieve the values?

Comment: @user1670340, if your "retrieving" code is a secret, then our answers will be secret too ))

Comment: This seems as if the `find()` doesn't find `sMethodName` and thus returns a past-the-end iterator, which you dereference (leading to undefined behaviour and garbage results).

Comment: @user1670340 To get good replies here on SO, it's best to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: That's what i believe so :( ... why garbage values...

Comment: There's no problem when i just running it with unit test... but when instrumenting it with code coverage this one occurs :(

Comment: I'd guess it's about a misunderstanding what `LPCTSTR` does used as a key value for the map. No way passing another 'string' value will find a valid entry in the map. I'd suggest using `std::string` as key type.

Comment: can you post how do you store enum to map?

Answer (score 5):

`std::map<LPCTSTR, long>` is rubbish. `LPCTSTR` is a typedef to `char*` (or `wchar_t*`), which means that the map compares keys based on the value of the **pointer**, not the string stored in it. You probably meant `std::map<std::basic_string<TCHAR>, METHODS>`. Don't use C data structures in C++.

Comment: This would be a learning experience not to use C data structure in c++ as a rookie I am in c++. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so your map returns an uninitialized value.. its not related to the enum.

Comment: Hi your right is not enum its my map... thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Angew pointed you probably mean: `std::map<std::basic_string<TCHAR>, METHODS>.` and you better not use C style string here. But if you are sure sMethodName hold posibly exactly one of the pointers you used to build the map, you still need to test if `find` hav actualy finded it (dont return `.end()`) and only than use `->second`.

Comment: I tested it with find and it return the values. But when, I profile my code for code coverage since I'm unit testing it... I get uninitialised values.

Comment: The real culript is my map :(

Comment: The fix was changing LPCTSTR to CString.... Thanks guys for your help.